# Non repeating positive random numbers, over a given range

Tags: vb6

am generating a game using vb 6.0, at one face i need to generate non repeating random numbers between 1 and 100. am using the following code for generating the random numbers

```
dim n(10) as integer
for i=0 to 9
n(i)=round(rnd*100) 
next i
```

the code is within a for loop hence it generate 10 Nos. randomly, but it includes repeating numbers and also '0', is their any suggestion to avoid repeating numbers and '0'
then **output** of my code is:

n()={**42**,14,10,22,5,**42**,12,**0**,59,72}

the numbers 42 is appear two times in the array and 0 cannot be avoided

thanks in advance

Comment: Computers can't generate random numbers of their own resources. A random number means that 9 between 1 and a 100 will have a 1% chance of being the next number. This is critically important in sampling. Computers do semi-random numbers that will repeat patterns. To prevent patterns seed the random number generator with the time, so each number is from a different pattern. This won't give a correct distribution. I can't remember my stats maths. But 42 will appear every now and then close together in any random generation. So it's not wrong that 42 appears twice - for a random sequence.

Comment: Dictionaries allow you to check for duplicates.

Comment: @Noodles: Patterns are irrelevant with a modern PRNG. Numbers won't repeat within the remaining 5 billion years of this planet. And seeding does not affect distributions at all. Seeding is a PRNG thing anyway, and math generally assumes true RNG's.

Comment: @MSalters If your range is integers 1 to 100, you can't avoid duplicates after 100 numbers, and they are almost unavoidable already around 50, statistically speaking. On average, expect a duplicate every 10 numbers (I think; feel free to attempt a formal proof).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple technique

```
Dim n(10) As Integer
Dim choice(100) As Integer
' Create a list of possible numbers
For i = 0 To 100
    choice(i) = i
Next
' Populate the array with unique numbers
For i = 1 To 10
    lastix = 101 - i
    ' Find one that has not been selected
    ix = Round(Rnd * lastix)
    ' Assign it
    n(i) = choice(ix)
    ' Replace with one that has not been used
    choice(ix) = choice(lastix)
Next
```

You can use the same technique for shuffling cards.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid 0, multiply by 99 and add 1. To avoid duplicates, keep track of what you generated and retry if you get a duplicate. (Since you need only a few numbers. If you need many, shuffle an array of all possible outcomes and take the initial members.)

Comment: if you don't mind will you please give the code segment

Answer (score -1):

the solution below is not the fastest, but makes up by that for being easy ...

it uses a hidden listbox control which contains the required values and retreives a random one every time

the values in this example are just the squared numbers of the index

run the project and click the command button to see what happens. it should show messageboxes with the square numbers in random order

```
'1 form with:
'1 listbox control : name=List1
'1 command button  : name=Command1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  'generate a new random sequence every time
  Randomize Timer
  'loop through the list and retreive 1 random value at a time
  With List1
    Do While .ListCount > 0
      intIndex = Int(Rnd * .ListCount)
      MsgBox .List(intIndex)
      'remove the used item from the list
      .RemoveItem intIndex
    Loop
  End With 'List1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  'hide listbox
  List1.Visible = False
  'fill listbox with values (squares)
  List1.Clear
  For intIndex = 1 To 10
    List1.AddItem CStr(intIndex * intIndex)
  Next intIndex
End Sub
```

btw i am just using 10 numbers so you dont have to click through 100 messageboxes :)